# How to ls! inside a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to write a script that displays files which do not have a .py extension
Here is a small snippet of the code i am writing.

```
   echo " - Creating"
   cd ${dirs[$directory]}
   file=$(ls -pd !(*.py) | grep -v /)
   echo $file
```

But I keep getting -

```
command substitution: line 54: syntax error near unexpected token `('
command substitution: line 54: `ls -pd !(*.py) | grep -v /)'
```

Comment: `shopt -s extglob` is mandatory.

Comment: What would be the right way. There are only 2 files in the folder one is a .py and one has a random extension

Comment: shopt actually made it work :) thank you

Comment: As an alternative, with `bash` you can use `cd /the/directory; GLOBIGNORE='*.py'; echo *` to get a list of names in the directory with the ones ending in `.py` omitted.  See the `bash` man page description for the `GLOBIGNORE` environment variable.

Comment: Should be `set -o extendedglob; files=( $dirs[$directory]/^*.py(N.:t) )` and in `zsh` instead of `bash`. The output of `ls` is not post-processable reliably.

Comment: Thank  you everyone.